# Why XML placed in /res/xml generates XmlPullParserException (no error when in /res/raw)?

Tags: android, xml-parsing, android-pullparser

I place the local XML file into `res/raw` and then loads it into `InputStreamer` object. It works fine and I am able to parse its content.

When I place the same XML into `res/xml`, I get `XmlPullParserException` saying it can't find the START tag.

I use this code to fill `InputStream` object:

```
 InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.data);
```

and this line to load the XML from `/res/xml`:

```
InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.xml.data);
```

Why is this happening? If the 2nd approach is the wrong one, what is then the purpose of `res/xml`?

Comment: Don't you mean `R.xml.data` in the second bit of code?

Comment: @KenWolf Yes, sorry. Copy/paste oversight.

Comment: `getXML()` doesn't return an InputStream... it returns an XMLResourceParser. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getXml(int)

Comment: @KenWolf Hm, you are right. I typed the second example from my head :). Anyway, is there a way to read XML from `res/xml` at all? Or this folder has another purpose? All samples I found use `res/raw`.

Comment: Answered in an answer :). Couldn't find a definitive tutorial but there are a few around for `XMLResourceParser`.

Answer (score 0):

`getXML()` doesn't return an `InputStream` so I'm not sure how your code compiles. It returns an `XMLResourceParser`.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getXml(int)

> Return an XmlResourceParser through which you can read a generic XML resource for the given resource ID.

The purpose of `/res/xml` is it's a handy place to store XML and later parse it! Sometimes you don't need an `InputStream` :)

Answer (score 0):

You can read it like this:

```
void parseXml(int xmlId){
    Resources res = context.getResources();
    //Xml parserer
    XmlResourceParser parser = res.getXml(xmlResource);

    while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {

         //A start tag is reached
         if(parser.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG){

             //Which tag is
             if(parser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Name"){
                 //Do something when a <Name> tag is reached
                 //and so on ...
             }
         }

    }
}
```